# Spring Java Microservice war size is too large

Tags: java, spring, microservices

Every time when we release on our production server, we need to copy 3-4 war(microservice war) file of size approx 150-200 MB. Even though we simply change a small thing in our code, but all maven dependency are combined to the war so the file size is very big.

Is there any way to reduce the size of war or how can we simply deploy our code not all the dependency with them?

Comment: Do you use WebSphere?

Comment: You need to add more information to the question. The web container? Linux/Windows? Monolith, distributed? replication? etc.  In short, it will be helpful to add a /lib folder in the prod server, with all the dependencies.. and then mark them as provided in the maven pom file. make sure to include the /lib in the startup scrip of the application.

Comment: And why is that too large? You have libraries, that libraries are required for your application to run. If you have libraries you don't need don't include them. The suggestion to make those things shared libraries might help but might also lead to class loading issues (depending on how your container loads things and who says that all your dependencies are there, what do you do with multiple versions etc. etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Make the 3rd party dependencies that are not going to get upgraded soon available on the classpath. jBoss's Wildfly uses the notion of modules allowing to strip down the war to the minimum making the deployment fast.